# Change IE8 Developer Tool Font

Tags: ie-developer-tools

How to change the courier new font that is used by IE8 developer tools, on Windows 2003 server to Consolas? Consolas is the default font while running IE8 on Winodws Vista/7.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the font used in the script debugger can't be changed and is built in.